# How to calculate the sum of integers from arrays

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is another way to calculate the sum of integers. Are there any built-in functions, or different ways to count this?

I create an empty array

```php
$arr=array(14, 13,"Cat",16,"Dog", 13.8, 14.5);
$arr2=array();
```

I found an empty integer and pushed into empty array

```php
foreach ($arr as $val){
    if(is_int($val)){
        array_push($arr2, $val);
    } 
}
```

and then i summed all integer

```php
$sum=0;
foreach($arr2 as $val2){
    $sum += $val2;
}
echo $sum;
```

Is my way correct?

Comment: Do you want a value like 13.0 for example, to be included in the new array or not?

Comment: What would you need the helper array for, you can just do `$sum += $val;` instead of array_push in the first loop, and do away with the second one.

Comment: @SimonGoater i dont want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of calculating the sum of these integers is basically okay.
Take a look at array_filter() and array_sum() function in the php-docs to get rid of these foreach-loops:

```
$arr = array(14, 13,"Cat",16,"Dog", 13.8, 14.5);
$arr2 = array_filter($arr, 'is_int');
$sum = array_sum($arr2);
echo $sum;
```